# types.reference not resolving the reference in mobx-state-tree

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am writing a search function that returns an array of `ModelA` or `ModelB` but when I use the references in my component, the reference is still a string. From the docs, I was expecting this to be the actual `ModelA` or `ModelB` so I feel like I am doing something wrong.

In my root store I create an array of references like this:

```
searchResults: types.array(
      types.union(
        types.late(() => types.reference(ModelA)),
        types.late(() => types.reference(ModelB)),
      ),
),
```

When I get them back from the request they are loaded into the store (I check by doing `store.modelBs.get(<one of the ids>)` but the component still gets the array of strings:

[image]

Does anyone know if this is valid/what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity, I found that it isn't possible to have an array of references that contain more than one type. Mobx-state-tree cannot determine what type of model the id references and throws the error: `Failed to resolve reference 'idB1' to type 'AnonymousModel'`.

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-leftpad-j0egz?file=/src/App.tsx)

edit: The way to accomplish this is to use the [dispatcher config option](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/overview/types#utility-types) for the union type like in this comment: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/1162#issuecomment-459742443